# understanding $\left\{x \in[0,1] / \sim \ : \ \max _{i \in[0, n-1]}\left\{\min _{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|4^{i} x+k\right|\right\}<1 / 4\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For integer values of $i$ and $n$, how do I describe the set

$$\left\{x \in[0,1] / \sim \ : \max _{i \in[0, n-1]}\left\{\min _{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|4^{i} x+k\right|\right\}<1 / 4\right\}$$

where $\sim$ indicates the identification of $0$ and $1$, i.e. $0$ and $1$ are glued together. 
Describe means simplify it enough to have a clear picture of the points $x$ contained in this set.
I don't know how to deal with the max-min expression. I have tried specific values for $i$ and $x$, but it didn't seem to help. thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: how would you understand the set if $4$ is replaced by $10$? For instance, let $x = 0.123$. What is $\max_{i} \{\min_k |10^x+k|<1/10\}$? Multiplying $x$ by $10^i$, we have numbers like $0.123, 1.23, 12.3, 123, 1230$ etc (depending on the value of $n$), so $\min_k |10^x+k|$ is the smallest distance from these numbers to an integer. Now what if $4$ is replaced by $10$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is a fixed integer. To check whether

$y\in S:=\left\{x \in[0,1] / \sim \ : \max _{i \in[0, n-1]}\left\{\min _{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|4^{i} x+k\right|\right\}<1 / 4\right\}$,

fix an integer $i$, check the distance between $4^iy$ and each $k\in \mathbb Z$ and select the integer $k(i)$ for which $|4^iy-k(i)|$ is mimimum. Now, $y\in S$ if and only if the maximum of these numbers over $0\le i\le n-1$ is less than $1/4$.

For example,

if $n=4$ and $y=1/2$, we have to check $|1/2+k|,|2+k|,|8+k|,|48+k|$ so $k(0)=[0],\ k(1)=-2,\ k(2)=-8$ and $k(3)=-48$ and the maximum of the associated distances is $1/2>1/4$ so $y=1/2\notin S.$

And

if $x=1/\pi,$ then $k(0)=[0],\ k(1)=-1,\ k(2)=-5,\ k(3)=-15$ and the associated distances are $1/\pi,\ (4/\pi-1)\approx .273,\ (16/\pi-5)\approx .0930,(48/\pi-15)\approx .279 $ and the maximum of these numbers $1/\pi>1/4$ so $y=1/\pi\notin S$.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  The associated distance to $k(0)$ is $|1/2 + 0|=1/2$  (not $0$).  So, shouldn't we have that $y=1/2 \notin S$?

Comment: @Loli Yes! Thanks. I will correct.